# How to setup cron job on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, cron, rss

I am hosting Tiny Tiny RSS site hosted on

**Amazon Linux AMI**

To update the feed automatically I have to run the following Cron job.

Reference
http://tt-rss.org/redmine/projects/tt-rss/wiki/UpdatingFeeds

`*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/tt-rss/update.php --feeds --quiet`

Here is the step I did:

```bash
sudo su
cd /etc
crontab -e
# add this line 
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/tt-rss/update.php --feeds --quiet
```

But I still got the message "Update Daemon is not running".

May I know, is this correct step for Cron job?

Comment: Can you post the result of $ /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/tt-rss/update.php --feeds

Comment: This looks like something that is run once every 30 minutes and once complete stops, rather than it being a daemon. Unfortunately the link povided doesn't actually link to the instructions. ;)

Answer (score 9):

You should enter these commands on **Amazon Linux 2**:

```
sudo systemctl start crond
sudo systemctl enable crond
```

Comment: I'm getting:
`sudo systemctl start crond`
`sudo: systemctl: command not found`
`sudo systemctl start crond`
`sudo: systemctl: command not found`

Comment: Maybe you're using Amazon Linux 1, it works on the latest Amazon Linux 2

Comment: Tried the latest amazon linux 2

Comment: Gal if you already ran sudo su - then you don't need to incluse `sudo` in the command.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like `crond` is not running. In which case:

```
service crond start
chkconfig crond on
```

Answer (score 4):

You should first inspect the cron log file `/var/log/cron` and look for any errors. This will probably give you the answer. Also make sure you can run the command successfully on the command line (`/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/tt-rss/update.php --feeds --quiet`).

Answer (score 1):

Please check the spaces, it could be because of spaces are not placed correctly

Answer (score 1):

Simply do : * * * * * wget -o - -q -t 1 "your url with cron file"

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the "--quiet" part from your cron command and check the log and feed again